# What can Cause Duplicate File Names?

Tags: filesystem

As you can see below, I somehow have duplicate file names.  I'm not sure if the files themselves are duplicate.  Any idea how this can happen?  The PI is running Raspbian Jessie.

[image]

Comment: That's not duplicate - check the last character.  k vs K.

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks. I only noticed it when copying the directory via samba to windows and it flagged the second copy as trying to overwrite the first. I believe windows files are case insensitive.

Comment: I guess the real answer is poor eyesight :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not duplicate - check the last character. k vs K